# Spark broadcast variables: large maps

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am broadcasting a large Map (~6-10 GB). I am using sc.broadcast(prod_rdd) to do that. However, I am not sure whether broadcasting is meant only for small data/files and not for larger objects that I have. If former, what is the recommended practice? One option is to use a NoSQL database and then do the lookup using that. One issue with that is I might have to give up performance since I will be going through a single node (Region server or whatever equivalent of that is). If anyone has any insight into performance impact of these design choices, that will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's in the map? Can you split it up while processing or does every shard need the whole map?

Comment: Unfortunately, every shard needs the complete map. It has a mapping between users and their historical activity along the time dimension.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if you could perhaps use mapPartitions and read the map once per partition rather than broadcasting it?